# Uncaught exception causes app crash in Sails JS ~0.12.11

Tags: crash, sails.js, uncaught-exception

Error is:
event.js line number 160
Unhandled exception.

This error occured after an error was unhandled by utils.js
Due to Error: write EPROTO 139889615579008:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:

App crashes immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function: (req, res, next) {
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(er) {});
d.add(req);
    d.add(res);
    d.run(function() {
        next();
    });
}

Adding this to a common function used in config/http.js worked.
```